# Can't login xfce directly

Tags: xfce, xrdp

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. I can log in `xfce` session through `xrdp` from another `windows` machine, but when I tried to log in `xfce` on that PC directly, the screen just flash to black screen for a second and return to login page.

The reason for that and how can I fix it?

Comment: You have given no OS/release details.  Please do.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks, pls check the update.